# Is modality always involved when we talk about the future?

Tags: modal-logic

When I make statements about causes in the future like "Cold causes frost to form on the window.", am I unavoidably involving modality even though i'm not using modal auxiliaries?

Can modality be avoided when making statements about the past, present and future or is it necesserily involved?

Comment: At least contemporary *Linear Temporal Logic* assumes so...